# RXJS Observable doSomething onComplete

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

I would like to use the RXJS Observable. Basically it works fine, but I need not just to react when *observer.next()* but also when *observer.complete()* is called.
How do I get the event of OnComplete of an RXJS Observable? In my opinion the RXJS doc is confusing.

```
export class Service {
    myMethod():Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create((observer:any) => {
        for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
         observer.next(i);
        }
        if(true==true) {
            // this event I need
            observer.complete();
        } else {
            observer.error(xhr.response);
        }
    }
}

export class Component() {
    // constructor etc.

    doSome() {
        this.service.myMethod()
        // Here I would like to get OnComplete event
          .catch(this.handleError)
          .subscribe((num:any) => {
            console.log(num);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The subscribe method accepts three callbacks. The last one is for the complete event.

```
doSome() {
  this.service.myMethod()
      .subscribe((num:any) => {
        console.log(num);
      }, (err) => {
        this.handleError(err);
      }, () => { // <----
        this.handleComplete();
      });
}
```

You could also leverage the `finally` operator for this.

```
doSome() {
  this.service.myMethod()
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .finally(this.handleComplete) // <----
      .subscribe((num:any) => {
        console.log(num);
    });
}
```

**note:**
there is a difference between the two examples in case we have errors:
if we would add `console.log`s we would see that in the first case
only `handleError` is printed

```
-> handleError
```

in the second case

```
-> handleError
-> finally
```

in other words `finally` is always called, were `complete` is not.

Comment: This worked for me .finally( () => this.handleComplete )

Comment: There is a difference between the two
in the first case, if you get an error, handleComplete will not be called
but finally (finalize) is always called

Comment: newer rxjs have ffinalize operator which you can use inside pipe

Answer (score 4):

As Thierry Templier answered one option is to leverage the `finally`/`finalize` ([rxjs docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html))
(but it's not the same as using the `complete` event, see the notes)

---

**last**

Another option to do something on complete is `last` ([rxjs/last](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html))

[image]

Comment: thank you, this was a bit confusing the fact that finally executes on complete or unsubscribe, it's not indicated in the notes at all.