# TypeScript/RxJS - Observable subscribe() method complete() not running

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've had a good look around to try and solve this but can't find an answer that works.

I'm trying to implement a callback for an additional function when a subscribe() method successfully returns an 'contacts$' observable, but using complete() on the subscription does not do anything.

I've also tried using finally() on the observable as suggested elsewhere, but this also doesn't work.

Using complete():

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getContacts().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.contacts = data;
            console.log('NewInvoice.contacts:', data);
            this.selectedContactId = this.contacts[0].id;
            console.log('selectedContactId: ' + this.selectedContactId);
        },
        error => {
            console.error('Error getting contacts via subscribe() method:', error);
        },
        () => {
            this.getSelectedContact();
        }
    )
}
```

Using finally():

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getContacts()
        .finally(() => console.log('a'))
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.contacts = data;
                console.log('NewInvoice.contacts:', data);
                this.selectedContactId = this.contacts[0].id;
                console.log('selectedContactId: ' + this.selectedContactId);
            },
            error => {
                console.error('Error getting contacts via subscribe() method:', error);
            },
            () => {
                this.getSelectedContact();
            }
    )
}
```

Method for callback on observable completion:

```
getSelectedContact() {
    this.contactsCollection.doc(this.selectedContactId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        this.selectedContact = snapshot.data() as Contact;
        console.log('selectedContact:', this.selectedContact);
    })
}
```

Comment: look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205074/rxjs-observable-dosomething-oncomplete). I hope it will help you

Comment: Can't tell without `getContacts` source.

Comment: @Roham Rafii - That answer to that post literally describes how to do what I've shown in my question is not working...

Comment: What's the value of this.selectedContactId inside getSelectedContact()? Is the value already set when getSelectedContact() is called?

Comment: There are a few differences. That answer uses `finally`, `catch` and `subscribe` .

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without more info, but I'll give a shot:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getContacts()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.contacts = data;
          console.log('NewInvoice.contacts:', data);
          this.selectedContactId = this.contacts[0].id;
          console.log('selectedContactId: ' + this.selectedContactId);
        },
        error => {
          console.error('Error getting contacts via subscribe() method:', error);
        },
        () => {
          this.getSelectedContact()
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe((a) => console.log(a));
        }
      )
  }
```

And :

```
getSelectedContact() {
    return this.contactsCollection.doc(this.selectedContactId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        this.selectedContact = snapshot.data() as Contact;
        console.log('selectedContact:', this.selectedContact);
    })
}
```

Or a little cleaner :

```
    const callback = (a) => console.log(a);
  ...
    () => {
      this.getSelectedContact(callback);
    }
  ...
    getSelectedContact(callback) {
      this.contactsCollection.doc(this.selectedContactId).ref.get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          this.selectedContact = snapshot.data() as Contact;
          console.log('selectedContact:', this.selectedContact);
        })
        .then(a => callback(a));
    }
```

Lastly as @Picci suggested :

```
this.getContacts()
    .last()
    .exhaustMap((data) => this.getSelectedContact(data))
    .map(a => console.log(a))
    .subscribe();
```

Beware that all the above code is absoultely not tested and only for reference.

Comment: Carefull: subscribe within subscribe is not a good way to manage Obaservables - better `switchMap` or `mergeMap`, depending on the case

Comment: yeah I know ... but a switchmap it is not what he asked. He wants some function to be called at the complete and the result (finally) passed to another function.

Comment: `switchMap` combined with `last` should do the trick, at least I think, without having to subscribe within a subscription

Comment: @Picci yes .. "last" is probably what he needs ... update the answer with this option. +1

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a solution to this scenario unfortunately. The getSelectedContact() method shouldn't have any parameters passed to it, it's just a callback, and the exhaustMap() method with/without the parameter returns the error "Argument of type '(data: Contact[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Contact[], index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'". (Sorry about the formatting)