# Why does onCompleted for Observable not have values of form?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms

**Goal**: I would like to get the value of an input on an Angular reactive Form.
I saw that it was null unless i did a timeout, so I tried using *onCompleted*() of the observable

As per [RXJS Observable doSomething onComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205074/rxjs-observable-dosomething-oncomplete) and https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol

I figured I would need to use the addControl method. However I am not able to get the value (it prints to console as null)

```
ngOnInit() {
    GetUserProfile();
}

public GetUserProfile()
{
    this.aa.GetProfile(id).subscribe(resp => {
        this.user = resp;           

        this.aa.GetPref(id).subscribe(resp =>{
            this.email = resp.Email;

            // Form Configuration
            this.createForm();                
            this.isLoaded = true;                   
        })
    },

    err => {
            console.log(err);
    },

    () => {
            console.log("On completed?");
            this.spanish = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("spanish2")).value
            console.log(this.spanish);
                this._profileForm.addControl('spanish3', new FormControl(this.spanish) );
          }
    );
}

createForm() {
                this._pForm = this.fb.group({
                            'spanish2': new FormControl()
                });
}
```

**Actual Result**: It prints out "On completed?", but it also says "Cannot read property 'value' of null" in reference to:

```
this.spanish = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("spanish2")).value
```

I **expected** it to have the value at this point. It only works if I use setTimeout.

HTML:

```
<mat-card class="patient-card">
    <mat-card-title class="text-center">
        My Profile
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>

        <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" *ngIf="!isLoaded">
                <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="isLoaded">
                <form [formGroup]="_pForm" novalidate>
                   <mat-form-field class="input-width" [class.hide-element]="true">
                        <input matInput placeholder="Spanish" id="spanish2" formControlName="spanish2" i18n-value="@@AiBrErQv_G2_91" value="Spanish">
                   </mat-form-field>                                
                </form>
        </div>

    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: That block is surrounded by a `*ngIf` that depends on an asynchronously set class property `isLoaded`. That input#spanish2 may simply not exist at the moment the `document.getElementById('spanish2')` is executed. You shouldn't count on `setTimeout()` either, as depending on how long the async call takes to resolve, the amount of time could vary.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky if I grab the element and try to print to console, Inside of a if(this.isLoaded) .. nothing happens. What am I missing here? Should I just create a separate hidden form that doesnt do this to grab the values from?

Comment: Yes, it will be still an issue even if you put it right after `isLoaded` is set as rendering isn't instant. You should avoid using `document.getElementById()` entirely. Try instead using the API provided by Reactive Forms to get/set the value.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky , only reason I am using getElementById is I am translating from english to spanish using i18n, so interpolated values are not known in typescript. I am creating hidden inputs and grabbing their i18n translated values, then in the typescript using that dynamically translated value to place into the real form.